# Raising attached events with EventTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

I have a class, `MyAttachedEventClassAquarium` that defines a custom attached as taken from the MSDN documentation. I have a `Window` that uses `EventTrigger` in XAML to hook the event to be handled on the `Window`'s viewmodel. The viewmodel is declared as a local resource.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:WinVM x:Key="myWinVM" />
</Window.Resources>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="NeedsCleaning" SourceName="MyAttachedEventClassAquarium">
        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MyCustomEventWasRaised" TargetObject="{StaticResource myWinVM}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I use the window's own RaiseEvent to raise the attached event from a button press handler:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Window1)((Grid)((Button)sender).Parent).Parent).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MyAttachedEventClassAquarium.NeedsCleaningEvent));
    }
```

Why won't my handler be called?

Thanks in advance.

B.

Comment: Did you check the output window for any errors?

Comment: Yes. There were no errors in the output window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(EDITED)

This approach to hooking events for a ViewModel to process looks unlikely to be maintainable. To troubleshoot it it might be a good idea to use the Snoop utility to take the visual and logical trees apart, to make sure that the objects you're casting, all of which implement a RaiseEvent method, are in fact the objects you want.

You might also need to define your SourceName parameter as a resource on your Window.

Those are guesses, and they describe a very different approach to message passing than MVVM patterns call for. Rather than digging into your logical tree like that, which is a very brittle approach, use the documented and proven patterns found below and elsewhere: Access the `DataContext` of your `Window` and call the VM method directly. Or, implement an `ICommand` in your ViewModel class and bind commands to it.

This first approach breaks the most pure approaches to MVVM but, it will work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var VM = this.DataContext As WinVM;

       if (VM != null) 
       {
         VM.MyCustomEventWasRaised();
       }
    }
```

Another approach is to implement an `ICommand` on your ViewModel class, and configure the `Button` in the View to use the command:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Command="{Binding NeedsCleaning}" />
```

This latter will eliminate the need for any XAML code-behind code in most cases.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer that raising of the event mechanics were of secondary interest in this case. I would be interested in why having raised the attached event on the window instance which is part of the visual tree did not invoke the handler declared in the EventTrigger portion of the XAML.

Comment: Having never seen anyone approach ViewModel messaging that way, I can't say. I've edited the answer with some comments that might help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the problem is `SourceName` -- that needs to be an instance, not the class name?  If I add the event source to the visual tree as "aquarium", and change the "SourceName" to "aquarium", then the action gets triggered:

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:WinVM x:Key="myWinVM" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="NeedsCleaning" SourceName="aquarium">
            <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MyCustomEventWasRaised" TargetObject="{StaticResource myWinVM}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <StackPanel>
        <my:MyAttachedEventClassAquarium x:Name="aquarium" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Click="button1_Click" Content="Raise Event" />
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    aquarium.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MyAttachedEventClassAquarium.NeedsCleaningEvent));
}
```

---

Just adding: the above approach seems to work *only* if I both raise the event on the aquarium object, and *also* use the same aquarium object as the EventTrigger's `SourceName`.  This seems to be something to do with the [System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interactivity.eventtrigger%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) class (bug?), because when I use the [DependencyObject.Triggers.EventTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.aspx) class, the event bubbles like you would expect.